# Countdown function doesn't display last number in 3-2-1 countdown

Tags: javascript, html

Pretty much what the title says. When the countdown starts, it goes "3", "2", and then executes the function that's supposed to launch when the timer hits zero, skipping the display of the number "1".

The actual timer output is displayed in a separate `div` element, you'll see in my code below.

I've seen some answers on here about faulty countdown clocks but a lot of them use jQuery whereas I'm just using vanilla JavaScript and the use of libraries is still a bit confusing to me.

```js
var count = 3;

function startTimer() {
    var timer = setInterval(function() {startTimer(count);}, 1000); 
    if(count === 0){
        clearInterval(timer);
        ranCoord(); //function to run when timer hits zero.
    } else {
        document.getElementById("target").innerText = count;
        count--;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="start">
   <img src="images/start-default.png" onclick="startTimer();" alt="Click Here"/> 
</div>

<div id="target"></div>
```

I noticed that if I include the `var count=3` variable inside the `startTimer();` function, the countdown doesn't work either, it just stays at number 3. Does anyone know why this is?

Also, if I include the `var timer = setInterval(function() {startTimer(count);}, 1000);` *outside* the function then it runs automatically on page load, which is not what I want. I want the countdown to start on the click of a button, and found that this worked when placed inside the function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to use a debugger for a bit. Place breakpoints and try to understand what happens. Look up timeout vs interval. Then I’ll gladly help

Comment: The main problem is that you're calling `setInterval` multiple times, meaning you're starting a bunch of intervals running parallel. Two will run and both decrement `count`, making it skip 1. Fixed version: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/u7twhor1/ (also, declaring a `var` inside a function means the var will cease to exist when the function ends, then be recreated with the initial value when the function runs again)

Comment: @Akxe thanks for your suggestion. I broke things down a bit with a debugger and although I still couldn't figure out what was wrong, it helped me see whereabouts in the code the issue was arising. Also, looking into timeout vs interval has helped.

Comment: @ChrisG I had a look at your fixed version and it's making much more sense. My original code looks so confusing in comparison now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the count variable is declared inside of the startTimer function, then each iteration of the timer will have its count value overwritten and so will not count down.

`setInterval` repeats its function indefinitely, so only needs to be called once outside of the loop, as opposed to `setTimeout` which only runs once and needs to be called each iteration.

An alternative approach using `setTimeout` would be:

```
function startTimer(count) {
    if (count <= 0) {
        ranCoord();
    } else {
        document.getElementById("target").innerText = count;
        setTimeout(function() { startTimer(--count); }, 1000);
    }
}
```

This version also avoids the use of a global variable, by passing the remaining count in as a parameter.

Comment: This is a useful approach to know, although my 3-2-1 countdown now returns "undefined", "NaN", "NaN". Update: I hadn't passed "3" as an argument for the function when it was first called. Works perfectly now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to call `startTimer` in the `setInterval`

```js
var count = 3;

function startTimer() {
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (count === 0) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      ranCoord(); //function to run when timer hits zero.
    } else {
      document.getElementById("target").innerText = count;
      count--;
    }
  }, 1000);

}

function ranCoord() {
  console.log("Timer hit 0")
}
```

```css
img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="start">
  <img src="images/start-default.png" onclick="startTimer();" />
</div>

<div id="target"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you not need to add more code you just need to simplify it like that

```
    var count = 3;
    function startTimer() {
        const timer = setInterval(function () {
            document.getElementById("target").innerText = count;
            count--;
            if (count <= 0) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                ranCoord();
            }
        }, 1000)
    }
```